# Series vs Serial vs TV show

Tags: meaning

I am confused - what is difference between these words?
Breaking Bad, True Detective are they series or serial?

On popular streaming sites I can see only TV series or TV shows, does it mean that serial is wrong or just not used now?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Would you please cite your references for *serial* and *series* and tell us what where you have difficulty?

Comment: Hi, i dont know which word i have to use to name tv shows in general. For example, True Detective, Breaking Bad, etc is a serials or series? and how call these in general? some my friends said that i could not call them serials , only series or tv shows. Like serial killer ,magazines.

Comment: These are TV series.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Perhaps [Series vs. serial thread](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86197/series-vs-serial) on Movies StackExchange, in which exactly the same question is asked, can help you?

Comment: in which situation can i use serial with tv shows? or cant?

Comment: So it is much better to use series than serials.

Comment: View Ceres through a telescope while you eat your cereal.

Comment: Could you explain what does it mean?

Comment: In the US in the early 20th century, the term serials was used for episodic short films which were shown in theaters on a weekly basis, each new film continuing the story from a previous week. Often an episode would end with a "cliffhanger," an unresolved dramatic scene. with the expectation that people would want to return the next week and pay to see what happens next. In the earlier days of television, serials were often shown as well, often as an afternoon entertainment, so a TV serial could mean such a short film.

Answer (score 4):

As a British English speaker, I would call an ongoing drama with a new story about the same characters each week a *series*, and a self-contained drama in weekly parts, such as a dramatization of a novel, a *serial*. However, American sources such as IMDb call the latter type a *mini-series*, because it is in a limited number of episodes.

Comment: Yeah, in the US "serial" is mostly used to refer to a story that is "serialized" in a magazine.

Comment: I have heard "series" used to refer to what I would call a season in American English. So a tv show is composed of multiple series in British English. But I would use tv series as a synonym for tv show. Can you corroborate that?

Comment: @KodosJohnson Yes, _series_ can also be used in that way.

Answer (score 4):

After reviewing M-W definitions of [series](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/series) (def. 1b) and [serial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serial) (entry 2 of 2, def. number 2) it is possible to conclude that:

- A **series** contains the **same characters** throughout, but **each episode is a different story**. So, you can start watching series from any episode (Martial Law, NYPD Blue, Friends, Colombo);
- A **serial** contains the **same characters** throughout again, but you should start watching from the first episode, because **each episode is a continuation of the previous one**. A serial, thus, should be thought of as a whole and undevidable story.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Not sure I completely understand ,so Breaking Bad is a serial ,because if i skip one episode i will not understand what happened,but people in previous comments said that these were tv series...So ,i think it is better use series,because it is more popular.

Comment: There is not a sharp dividing line between the two. It's common to have a combination of series and serial in one show. Even highly episodic TV series often have two part episodes and ongoing themes. Some crime shows will have a villain-of-the-week element combined with an overarching villain-of-the-season story line.

Comment: One reason for episodic TV shows is that by making each episode basically stand on its own, you had more options for syndication, something that streaming has basically killed off. My opinion is that streaming has increased the appeal of serial vs episodic storytelling for producers.

Comment: I agree that sometimes it is possible to have a combination of a series and a serial in one show. However, it is useful to know the original definitions of these two words so that to simply know more and to have more agile mind, so to say. In some topics - and this one is a good example - it is useful to understand what something _is_, and not what _to call_ something as annotating sometimes rather harms than helps. But if defining is important, and I am in no case implying that we should abandon annotation, I would call Breaking Bad a series in which episodes can sometimes work together.

Answer (score 3):

Any continuing program (as opposed to movies or specials) on TV is called a "series". This includes game shows, reality shows, sitcoms, dramas, etc.

A "serial" is a *type* of series, usually comedy or drama, where the episodes generally form part of an ongoing plot arc, rather than being mostly self-contained stories. In some cases the plot arc might only last for a season, in other cases there's a storyline that lasts through the entire run of the series.

The most common form of serial programs are "soap operas". But in recent years it has become more popular to make serialized dramas and comedies. "Breaking Bad" and "Lost" are some of the most well known examples of serialized dramas. On streaming services, serialized shows are popular because viewers can binge-watch them, making them like long movies.

Comment: The part of this answer that needs to be emphasised is that 'a "serial" is a type of series': that is what makes this answer crucially different from the others, which attempt to treat the two concepts as mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Ambitious_ph1lologist nailed it, his definition is absolutely correct. In terms of TV production, serials are actually older than series (The Forsyte Saga, 1967; Lost in Space and the like to the more recent Downton Abbey). Serials are almost always works of fiction, they consist of xy number of episodes, and each episode tells just one part of the plot, usually leaving viewers in suspense until the next episode. Mini series rarely have more than 2 or 3 parts. Series can be anything, from sitcoms, action/drama, docudrama, documentaries, music shows, entertainment... you name it. So TV series are everything, from popular sitcoms (Friends, The Big Bang Theory, Two and a Half Men), criminal drama (NYPD, Navy CSI, 911, Law and Order...), to documentary series and other shows (Property Brothers etc.) They're all categorized as series. The main difference is that with TV series, each episode is more or less a complete story, and screenplays are often created / contributed by a number of authors, while serials are usually based on works of literature - fiction, (for example on a novel by a single author). At least this is how TV industry (where I worked for nearly 40 years) categorizes TV shows.